# That's not the bounty text I selected

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-norepro, bounty

I added a bounty yesterday to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/output-a-playable-crossword-grid) and I chose the text "One of the answers is deserving of additional bounty". But when I pulled it up today to award it (hoping to have inspired votes from others in the meantime), the text is "Looking for an authoritative source". Do we even need that one here?

So I think there's a bug, because it's not the one I selected.

And the feature-request is to remove the "authoritative source" option altogether.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be much use for that message expect perhaps for [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions.

I haven't heard of other having trouble with getting the wrong text, but it is at least possible that the dialog box has gotten out of sync with the code somehow.

Your request goes over the heads of mere moderators. I don't know that the team will want to make per-site adjustments to the bounty texts, but a representative will likely be along sooner or later.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the solidarity. :)